# Query about the datetime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

what is the function of

```
    MAX(SUBSTRING(date,15))
```

in php?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Huh? What's "date"? in PHP it's a function that returns a date formatted to how you ask, so it could be anything. SUBSTRING is substr() if you want to try it for yourself.

Comment: Here "date" is a column name of a table in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not PHP, it's most probably MySql.

`SUBSTRING()` limits the string length of `date` from the specified starting position, in this case the 15th character.

`MAX()` will return the highest result, meaning the function will return the most recent date from the selected data set.

Comment: I think OP is well aware that `MAX(SUBSTRING())` is indeed not a php function, which is why the question `in php?`

Comment: I guess his question could be read both ways, it wasn't very clear

Comment: My mistake. It is part of a sql query which is written inside a php script.

Answer (score 0):

php also have [max](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php), and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). But If your code is some DB functions, they are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Here date may be some variable, what ever it may be substr(anything) will return single string, but max needs array as input if there only one parameter, so this statement I think is not correct

Refer [max documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)